# Ajax redirect resulting no route matches with carmen

Tags: ajax, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2, routes, carmen

Hie, i am using carmen gem for country and state listing.

my view code is,

```
<div class=" control-group">
  <%= f.label :country, :class => 'control-label' %>
  <div class="controls">
    <%= f.select :country, Carmen::Country.all.collect{|c| c.name}, {:selected => country}, :remote=>true %>
  </div>
</div>
<div class=" control-group">
  <%= f.label :state, :class => 'control-label' %>
  <div id="addressStates">
    <%= render :partial => 'experienceones/states', :locals => {:states => Carmen::Country.named('India').subregions.collect{|sub| sub.name }, :form => f} %>
    </div>
  </div>
```

partial state is,

```
<div class="controls">
  <%= fields_for 'experienceones' do |addr_form| %>
    <% if !@states.blank? %>
  <%= addr_form.select :state, @states, {:prompt => 'Select State'}, {:style => 'width: 180px'} %>
<% else %>
  <%= addr_form.text_field :state %>
<% end %>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

jquery is,

```
jQuery('select#experienceone_country').change(function() {
  var country = 'country=' + $('select#experienceone_country :selected').text();
  jQuery.ajax({
    url: '/experienceones/update_state_select',
    data: country,  
    dataType: 'html',
    success: function(data){
      jQuery("div#addressStates").html(data);

      },
  });
});
```

and in controller i have,

```
def update_state_select
  @states = Carmen::Country.named(params[:country]).subregions.collect{|sub| sub.name } || []
end
```

when i select country, i am able to get list of state successfully in select tag.

but i get error as,

```
No route matches [GET] "/experienceones/1/true"
```

i knw, true is result of my request

```
GET "/experienceones/update_state_select?country=######"
```

bt how can i avoid this?

my url for edit is

```
http://localhost:3000/experienceones/1/edit
```

if i use,

```
window.location.href = "/experienceones/<%= @experience.id %>/edit"
```

in ajax success, i get new edit page.

i want to redirect in same page (i.e edit page) bt with selected country and state.

How can i do this?

Same issue is for new.

Thank You.

Comment: got solution for this. I had given :remote=>true in country div tag, thats why it was giving me another url.